# AWS S3: .csv file is downloaded as .csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have 2 AWC accounts, each of them has one S3 bucket. I uploaded two same-size .CSV files to each of the S3 bucket.

When I try to **Download** or **Download As**, this file is downloaded as .CSV file in first account. BUT(!!) When I try to download this file from second account - it is downloading it as .TXT.

How can this happen? Both files are created in the same way: through Redshift UNLOAD query, that perform copying of selected data from Redshift to S3.

**UPDATE**:
**Can it be because in this account for this document , **Server side encryption is equal to AWS-KMS?**
I noticed that file, that converted from .csv to .txt has "Server side encryption: AWS-KMS", while .csv file that is downloaded as .csv - has "Server side encryption: NONE"

**UPDATE**: tried in different browsers - same result

[image]

Comment: Works fine here in Chrome, regardless of SSE-KMS or content type metadata (though I did not use Redshift).

Comment: @jarmod Hi. I tried Firefox and Chrome - same result.
I noticed that file, that converted from .csv to .txt has "Server side encryption: AWS-KMS", while .csv file that is downloaded as .csv - has "Server side encryption: NONE"

Comment: Right, but I'm saying that works fine here (SSE-KMS is server-side encryption with KMS).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the headers for each object in the AWS S3 console and compare the Content-Type values. `Content-Type` provides a hint to web browsers on what data the object contains.

If `Content-Type` does not exist or does not contain `text/csv`, add or modify the header in the S3 console or via your favorite S3 application such as CloudBerry.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. There is Content-type: txt/csv in file that is downloaded correctly and there is NO  Content-type values in file that is converted in .TXT. 
The problem is that, I cannot do it manually. I cannot go and modify each file. I have a lot of them, each day new files is added. I create this file through Redshift UNLOAD command. So not sure how to handle this

Comment: I do not know of a way to have Redshift specify the Content-Type header. Do the files with the issue already exist when you execute the UNLOAD command? If so, the headers will not be changed. Delete them first before the UNLOAD. Another idea is to use Lambda to process new files and if they have the .csv file suffix add the HTTP Content-Type header.

Comment: No, those files are not exist when the UNLOAD executes. UNLOAD creates new file in S3 buckets , that I specify

Answer (score 0):

John is right about the `Content-Type` not being `text/csv`. Sometimes, S3 will get it right and sometimes it won't. If you can't manually correct this yourself, you can run a **Lambda** function to do this for you everytime you upload a new object. You can use a Python 2.7 template **Lambda** function to download the object from the bucket, employ `mimetypes` library to `guess_type` for your S3 object, and then re-upload the file in the same bucket. You will need to trigger this function with S3 object upload and give it the necessary permissions (S3:GetObject).

**P.S.** This will work for files with any extension. If you know you are only going to upload `.csv` files, you can ignore the *mimetypes* and directly re-upload the object with

```
bucket.upload_fileobj(filename, key, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'text/csv'})
```

If the *mimetypes* cannot guess the typethen you might need to add the types, look at an example here https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/5209/mimetypes.add_type

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is `scala` solution (to specify content type):

```
val settingsLine: String = "csvdata1,csvdata2,csvdata3"
val settingsStream: InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(settingsLine.getBytes())

val metadata: ObjectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata()
metadata.setContentType("text/csv")

s3Client.putObject(bucketName, prefix, settingsStream, metadata)
```